# Web app with JPA doesn't work on extenal Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jpa

I've some problems with publishing my Dynamic Web application in Tomcat, on my VPS server.

I developed an application which contains Servlet( creating Entity Manager and doing operations on the database), and jar files - also Entity components are packed in jar file.
Application uses eclipselink and postgresql.

On Tomcat 7 Server installed witch eclipse, everything works fine, but when I try to deploy it  to Tomcat 7 Server on my VPS I'm getting an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class pl.marekbury.controller.StoreServer
```

and the root cause

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [pl.marekbury.controller.StoreServer/PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [pl.marekbury.controller.StoreServer].
```

I had also the same error on my localhost eclipse-integrated server, but i found a solution (somwere here, on stack) to chcange eclipselink version, after I did id, error's gone.

I'm deploying app in these way:
- export war from eclispe
- deploy it trough tomcat web manager

I tried:
- Change server to Tomee
- Place all jar libs in WEB-INF/lib

Structure of application folder after deploying to tomcat:

```
 ----krzyzyk
      |   |---index.jsp
      |---META-INF
      |          |---MANIFEST.MF
      |
      |---WEB-INF
      |          |---web.xml
      |          |---lib
      |          |      |---all jar files(entities,servlet-api itd..)
      |          |
      |          |---classes
      |          |      |---META-INF(remain after making jar with entities)
      |          |      |---pl
      |          |      |     |---marekbury
      |          |      |     |        |---controller
      |          |      |     |        |       |---StoreServer.class
      |          |      |     |        |---model
      |          |      |     |        |       |---entities
      |          |      |     |        |       |       |---User.class (remain after making jar with entities)
```

index.jsp makes http request to servlet StoreServer

Any ideas how to make it run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. Error was caused by different Java versions on vps(oracle 1.7) and my computer(openJDK 1.7). I have made .WAR on VPS and everything works fine.